# Error in creating fuse project in Fuse IDE

Tags: appfuse

I am new to Fuse. I just started learning Fuse.

I have installed Fuse IDE (latest ver). And set the reference to apache maven installation directory.

I started creating a new fuse project as mentioned in the document but when I click on the Finish button I have an error as  "Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3".

I tried to clen build the new POM.xml I have the below errors:

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO]

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Building A Camel Spring Route 1.0.0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Downloading: "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
"

### [INFO] -------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 0.875s

[INFO] Finished at: Mon Feb 11 19:31:43 IST 2013

[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.4.1 from/to central (repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] "http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException"

I tried all the solutions suggested in the link.
As disabled the firewall, has the correct reference to the local repository, and I could see all the plug ins in the repository.

I deleted plugins and build the project again and I could see the plugins downloaded to the local repository.

And I removed the complete repository as suggested somewhere and tried, then we have a new repository but still the same error.

One observation is that the plugins doesnt have the jar files in it, so I manually downloaded the jars and placed in the repository, but still the error.

Please let me know what are the other options I need to try to solve this issue. As I have been trying this from last 2 days without success. Please help me on this.

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a http proxy/firewall. Apache Maven needs to download dependencies (eg JAR files) over the internet. And if it fails, then its usually you need to tell it about the http proxy you need to use.

See the FAQ at the Maven site
http://maven.apache.org/general.html#proxy-needed